# Import requests CPython error

Tags: python, python-requests

Whenever i try `import requests` in my Python code, i got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/V/Desktop/PY/web_scrape/zoro copy.py", line 2, in <module>
import requests
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>
from cryptography import x509
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from cryptography.x509.base import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 16, in <module>
from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 13, in <module>
from asn1crypto.keys import PublicKeyInfo
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\keys.py", line 22, in <module>
from ._elliptic_curve import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_elliptic_curve.py", line 51, in <module>
from ._int import inverse_mod
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_int.py", line 52, in <module>
if platform.python_implementation() == 'PyPy':
File "C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py", line 1417, in python_implementation
return _sys_version()[0]
File "C:\Python27\Lib\platform.py", line 1383, in _sys_version
repr(sys_version))
ValueError: failed to parse CPython sys.version: '2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you a lot.

Comment: how did you install `requests` and have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I installed requests using Pip and when i got the error, i uninstalled it and installed it again but the error is still there.

Comment: if you are using anaconda have you tried installing the package with anaconda? It looks like your `sys.version` is an unrecognized format because conda stuck their company name in it.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen How should i fix this ?

Comment: Is that anaconda's python importing stuff from a python.org directory? Should it really be doing that, or has something been done to the anaconda python import path? It's not just the requests module, but parts of python itself as well (platform.py)

Comment: @jonatan I fixed it by changing interpreter in Pycharm and uninstalling Anaconda.